# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.' in my Accounting Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ms-access-2016

I'm making an Accounting project in C# Visual Studio 2017 and I have three forms:

1. Login
2. Main
3. Product Entry

1st and 2nd form work properly, but when I clicked the button of Product Entry (3rd form),
project doesn't go to 3rd form and it shows this error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Invalid SQL statement; expected
>   'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.'

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;
using MetroFramework;

namespace MAARS_Software.Project
{
    public partial class frmProductEntry : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new 
OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["con"]);
        OleDbConnection conn = new 
OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=D:\Backup\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My 
Projects\Backups\MAARS Software\DataBase.accdb;
Jet OLEDB: Database Password = 654321");

    public frmProductEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmProductEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewData();
    }

    private void Save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Update_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Delete_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Exit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    void ViewData()
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Selct * from [Product]", 
con);
        //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //da.Fill(dt);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);                //Error stop here
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Select"  not "Selct" - the error message points you directly to your query.

Comment: hahah thnx I mistyped Selet work this is the problem now it work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo of `select` in `OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Selct * from [Product]", con);` 
 That should be like `OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Product]", con);`

Comment: hahah thnx I mistyped Selet work this is the problem now it works correctly